# Postgresql Ethiopian Date Format

Tags: postgresql, date, format

Is there a way to store a date in a PostgreSQL db using the Ethiopian date format? I'm trying to store 29th or 30th of February but it throws an error, because in the Julian calendar there's no such thing. Any inputs?

Comment: I don't know the answer for PostgreSQL (hence this is a comment, not an answer), but… Most DBMS store the DATE and TIME and TIMESTAMP data in a canonical form that is independent of the specific calendar in use. The values are transformed from string to canonical or from canonical to string under the guidance of the rules for the locale (current locale by default). I think your questions should be (1) does PostgreSQL support Ethiopian dates at all, (2) what locale settings are necessary to do so, and (3) can you control each field (so you can display Ethiopian and Julian at the same time).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I can confirm this for Postgres. Internal format in modern day Postgres is an [8-byte integer that counts the number of microseconds](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) since 1970. This is 100% independent of any locale, time zone or formatting. You need an Ethiopian locale that would accept string literals comprising a 30th of February ( I don't know if there is one). The internal value is then translated to the format requested by the client and back.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I'll tell you something new but...

Databases are used by programs or by interfaces, I never saw databases that are used by end-user in console with psql.

If you are develop an application, that must display dates in specific calendar, you can store date in PostgreSQL in `TIMESTAMP`. All operations with dates will work correct in database. But you have to implement conversion from `TIMESTAMP` into string representation and vice versa in your application manually. If this is most important thing for your application, you will do this.

All queries that must return date you will write with conversion into `DOUBLE PRECISION` e.g.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timestamp_field)
```

This returns `DOUBLE PRECISION` value that represents timestamp in numerical format.

All date parameters in queries you have convert from numerical presentation in `TIMESTAMP` using built-in function `to_timestamp`:

```
update table_name set
    timestamp_fileld = to_timestamp(1384852375.46666)
```

The other solution is to write psql functions that do this for you directly in queries, but anyway you need to handle each input/output of date fields in queries.